# Can use of a coupon be shown in order information?

Tags: coupon

I have created a coupon which I called click&collect, enabling customers to avoid paying freight by collecting their order from our physical shop. I would like the use of this coupon to show up on the order information, so I know that the order is special and I don't need to ship it. Can Magento do this?

Answer (score 0):

Gary Sullivan,If you want to place order from `magento,then you need to always select payment`.In a simple word,you `can not skip payment` step magento during chckout.

If want to skip payment then create an custom payment method which is not rewrite to third party and just pragmatically set this payment a during checkout payment and remove payment method UI from frontend

And regard on coupon.Magento  `are showing coupon code at order` and it is magento `default functionality`.